# How to return false if 0 rows affected with PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

How can I return false if 0 rows affected with PDO?

I have this method to execute a SQL query,

```
public function executeSQL($query, $params = array())
{

    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->connection->prepare($query);
        $params = is_array($params) ? $params : array($params);
        $stmt->execute($params);
        return true;

    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) 
    {
        // call the get_error function
        $this->get_error($e);
    }
}
```

So I can run a query like this below for updating a row in my table,

```
    $update = "
        UPDATE content_has_language
        SET text = ?
        WHERE content_id ?
        AND language_id IN
        (
            SELECT language_id
            FROM language AS l
            WHERE l.code = ?
        )
    ";

   $result = $this->connection->executeSQL($update,array(
               'xxx',
                '1',
                'en'      
    ));
```

And it always return true whether the row is matched and updated or not. But I need it to return **false** - **if** `0 rows affected. (Query took 0.0010 sec)`

Is it possible?

Comment: you can do away with that `$params = is_array($params) ? $params : array($params)` ternary, by changing your method signature to _only_ accept arrays (using type-hints): `public function executeSQL($query, array $params)`. You should, however make sure that the array is not empty: PDO will fail if the array does not contain a value for each placeholder, so add `if (count($params) !== 3) throw new InvalidArgumentException();`. Another alternative to the `is_array($x) ? $x : array($x)` ternary is a simple cast: `$params = (array) $params;`, that saves the overhead of a function call

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
return $stmt->rowCount() > 0;
```

Comment: or just `return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) ? true : false;`

Comment: You definitely don't need the else.

Comment: @Loz I do just `return $stmt->rowCount() > 0`

Comment: @turson I disagree, if you know the language `return $stmt->rowCount() > 0` is sooo much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: @Arth: I'd add brackets, though: `return ($stmt->rowCount() > 0);` Or possibly, to make it absolutely clear that you're returning a bool: `return !!$stmt->rowCount();` Seeing as 0 will evaluate to false, and the `!!` ensures the return value to be a bool...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem the `>` operator always returns a bool anyway thus `>` is way clearer than a double `!` on an integer. I don't massively like adding brackets here, it's so clear anyway, why bother? I could cede to them however.

Comment: @Arth: It's all a matter of personal preference, in the end. I'd probably `return $stmt->rowCount()`, as it is more communicative.  But I agree, a simple `$stmt->rowCount() > 0` more than enough, just wanted to be complete.

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem, I agree with return `return $stmt->rowCount()`. Always worth considering the options!

Answer (score 6):

Please consider

```
return $stmt->rowCount() > 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Or

```
return (bool) $stmt->rowCount();
```