# MYSQL Update only returns TRUE, not FALSE?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm using this to update a table. the `validator` is a randomly generated 20 character string, used in conjunction with other vars to verify data validity.

To my mind, the table should only update `Response` if `Validator` and `FixtureID` match the same row.

```
+-----------+----------------------+----------+
| FixtureID | Validator            | Response |
+-----------+----------------------+----------+
|         1 | 9eb593bd154b655019ad | U        |
|         1 | 4b80ac0ac204be8968e4 | U        |
|         2 | a2d278612994d3010595 | U        |
|         2 | c01171d690d5dfb141ff | U        |
|         3 | 22cd6e5b7f6dd6e76366 | U        |
```

// PHP script

```
    $query = "
        UPDATE 
            invites 
        SET 
            Response=:response 
        WHERE 
            Validator=:validator
            AND
            FixtureID=:FixtureID 
        ";
    $query_params = array(
        ':response'=>'Y',
        ':FixtureID'=>'1',
        ':validator'=>'9eb593bd154b655019ad'
    );
    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);

    if ( $result ) {
        echo 'Success';
    } else {
        echo 'Invalid';
    }
```

However, I can change validator to `x` and `$result` still returns as true.

I'd really appreciate a little direction as to why this might be happening?
Much appreciated.

Comment: It only returns `FALSE` if there's an error. It's not an error when nothing is updated.

Comment: `:response'=>'Y',` ? and your columns show `U`. Is this a question about behaviour?

Comment: So even if there are no rows where `FixtureID` and `Validator` exist together, this isn't considered an error, or `False?

Comment: It was successful, just 0 rows to update. Look at how many rows were affected, http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php.

Comment: Likely, the query is still executed successfully, just that no rows are being updated. You should check for `mysql_affected_rows()`.

Comment: @Stuart they're using PDO and not `mysql_`. Edit for castis: or `mysqli_`.

Comment: @castis see above comment

Comment: Oops i just saw the `mysql` tag and answered quickly... In this case you'll check for `rowCount()`

Comment: @Fred-ii- response is Y, N, or U ( Yes, No, or Unknown). I can update it no problem, Just trying to get a return value of updated rows.

Comment: @Stuart there was also the "pdo" tag ;-) and the code itself, since it contains the `:placeholders`.

Comment: Maybe dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24825751/how-to-return-false-if-0-rows-affected-with-pdo

Comment: Indeed @fred, ill say it again "i just saw the mysql tag and answered _too_quickly" :)

Comment: for self-improvement if you could explain your down votes that would be super, thanks.

Comment: @Stuart `rowCount()` was precisely what I was looking for thanks!

Comment: No worries @denski, apologies for my first comment that was evident i didn't read the question thoroughly! :)

Comment: I don't see a reason for this question to be downvoted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$count = $stmt->rowCount(); 
if ( $count > 0 ) {
     echo 'Updated'; 
} else {
     echo 'Not updated'; 
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

It returns `true` because your query was run successfully. The fact that it didn't change anything in the DB does not matter.

PDO can not guess that what you wanted is at least one update. It runs the query, and if there was no error - the query was successful.

If you need your app to handle such cases - you may want to consider first running `SELECT COUNT(*)` with the same `WHERE` conditions and report to the user that there's nothing to update.